# How to pass several named parameters to a function with purrr?

Tags: r

I have been trying to connect a pipe function with a *normal* function and set the return value to a new column. What I'm trying to do is to send the function the parameters and then continue chaining operations

This is the function that I'm trying to run with *purrr*:

```
fileDownloader<- function(url, path, log_attr){
    url <- as.character(url)
    path <- as.character(path)
    log_attr <- as.character(log_attr)
    res <- 0
    if (log_attr == "a"){
        text<-paste("Function invoked at ", as.character(Sys.time()), sep=" ")
        print(text)
        write.csv(text, file = "log.csv")
    }    

    if(!file.exists(path)){
        res <- tryCatch({                        
                        archivo <- curl_download(url=url, destfile=path)
                        res <-1
                    }
                    ,error=function(e){res <- -1}
                )
    }
    res
}
```

I have this dataframe that I'm trying to pipe

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(
    url=c("www.google.com", "yahoo.com", "bing.com", NA),
    file_name=c("mi_file1.txt", "mi_file2.txt", "mi_file3.txt", NA),
    attributes=c("a", "", "", NA),
    another_col=c("xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "111")
    )
```

This is the actual piping:

```
my_dataframe %>%
    filter(!is.na(url)) %>%
    # mutate(file_status = pmap(list(.$url, .$file_name, .$attributes), .f=fileDownloader) )
    # prints 212/321/131
    # mutate(file_status = map(.$url, path=.$file_name, log_attr=.$attributes, .f=fileDownloader))
    # works only with the first element
```

I have managed to "make it work" with *{walk}* but it does not return anything.

Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: `purrr::pmap_chr`?

Comment: If I do this: ```mutate(file_status = pmap_chr(list(.$url, .$file_name, .$attributes), .f=fileDownloader))```, I get this as parameters on the function: [1] "2 1 2" [1] "3 2 1" [1] "1 3 1" :(

Comment: Have you ever done `debug(fileDownloader)` and seen what arguments are actually being passed internally?

Comment: What are all of those octothorpes doing in the code? Please use [edit] to improve your question body .... do NOT use comments for that purpose.

Comment: I get no errors up to the the end of `filter(...)` ( and all the rest of the code is commented out), so whatever non-desired behavior might be at issue is unclear. And that's a basis for closure.

Comment: Hey @r2evans could you please put your comments as an answer so I can accept it? After trying again with debug I saw several weird things -I'm on a jupyter notebook running on a raspberry pi 3-, so I tried again on rstudio.cloud and the code worked. I recompiled ```purrr``` to the newest version and the code worked like a charm!

Comment: @StrayChild01, my comment really does not help solve the underlying problem as much as suggest a direction of investigation. I have an idea what it is, but I don't want to speculate and do not have time to finish the thought. Perhaps you can answer your own and (a few moments later) accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does this work for you:

```
my_dataframe %>%
  filter(!is.na(url)) %>%
  mutate(file_status = pmap_chr(list(.$url, .$file_name, .$attributes), .f = fileDownloader))
```

Comment: This was the function that helped me to pass the parameters. Another issue I had was that the purrr version was very old and didn't map the values correctly.